# "Insufficient Data Provided" when trying to create an AWS Service Catalog product

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-catalog

I keep getting this message every time I try to create a new product in Service Manager, even though I already filled up all the mandatory fields (and none of the optional ones).

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my CloudFormation template was invalid.

Always make sure to validate your template before uploading it:

`aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://path/to/your/template.yml`

**How did I figure it out?**

I was initially trying to create the product from `Administration -> PortFolios -> [My Portfolio] -> Upload new product`. This is where I got the error message on the OP

Later on I tried to do it from `Administration -> Products -> Upload new product` and the error message from this screen was actually helpful

[image]

Comment: This is just what was looking for!  Thank you for supplying the information on how to track down the error.  I encountered the same error, and this gave me the info I needed to fix the issue.